# Need to find the set these belong to

Tags: set-identification

Need to find the set these belong to.
Blue octagon, a shooter, mostly black.
And bananas!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This belongs to [Gorzan's Gorilla Striker (70008)](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=70008-1)

[image]

Identified by combination of following elements:

[Dark Azure Plate, Modified 10 x 10 Octagonal with 6 x 6 Open Center](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6063&colorID=153&in=A). Dark Azure is the only shade of blue this part exist in, event though on a picture it looked like to be blue.

[Projectile Arrow, Liftarm Shaft with Hollow Yellow Rubber End](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=57028c04&colorID=86&in=A)